# Magento2 - How to pass any custom static data to order email template?

Tags: magento2, orders, order-email

Is their any way we can pass some static data to order confirmation email template ?

And then use it as variable in email template ?

```
like {{var order.pickupDate}}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can add using Observer.

Create `events.xml` file on `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="email_order_set_template_vars_before">
        <observer instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Email\OrderSetTemplateVarsBefore" name="v4u_emailvar_observer_email_ordersettemplatevarsbefore_email_order_set_template_vars_before"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Create `OrderSetTemplateVarsBefore.php` on `app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/Email`

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer\Email;

use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;

class OrderSetTemplateVarsBefore implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    protected $customerRepository;

    public function __construct(
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
    ) {
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action $controller */
        $transport = $observer->getEvent()->getTransport();
        if($transport->getOrder() != null)
        {
            $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($transport->getOrder()->getCustomerId());
            $transport['userId'] = $customer->getId();
        }
    }
}
```

As per Our observer defined You can use

`{{trans 'User Id : '}}{{var userId}}`

For more info you can review [here](https://github.com/vrajeshpatel4u/v4u-magento2-custom-varible-in-emailTemplate)

Answer (score 0):

You can use trasnportbuilder for the same.
You can paas your custom data using the SetTemplateVars

```
$transport = $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId, 'template_id')
                ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $store_id])
                ->setTemplateVars([
                                 'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore(),
                                 'name'  => $name,
                                 'custom_data' => $data,
                                  ])
                ->setFrom('general') 
                ->addTo($email, $name)
                ->getTransport();
                $transport->sendMessage();
```

You can get these variables in email template by using

```
{{var name}}
{{var custom_data}}
```

Comment: Please check if it works for you.